# Classification Metrics for Sequential tagging in NLP

Tags: nlp, metrics, tagging, sequential, crf

I am writing one sequential tagging code in NLP using python google colab. As I have used crf layer in my model, I used crf.metrices to get the results . I had executed the following code :
//

```
 pred_cat = model.predict(X_te)
    pred = np.argmax(pred_cat, axis=-1)
    y_te_true = np.argmax(y_te, axis=-1)
    tags=['O', 'BOC', 'IOC','<pad>']
    from sklearn_crfsuite import metrics as crf_metrics
    print(crf_metrics.flat_classification_report(y_true=y_te_true,y_pred=pred,labels=tags))
```

//

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-510856efb26d> in <module>()
      1 from sklearn_crfsuite import metrics as crf_metrics
----> 2 print(crf_metrics.flat_classification_report(y_true=y_te_true,y_pred=pred,labels=tags))

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn_crfsuite/metrics.py in flat_classification_report(y_true, y_pred, labels, **kwargs)
     66     """
     67     from sklearn import metrics
---> 68     return metrics.classification_report(y_true, y_pred, labels, **kwargs)
     69 
     70 

TypeError: classification_report() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Can anyone please throw some light on this?

Comment: cannot really find your problem without types or samples of your `y_true`, `y_pred`, etc